# What is greater: nevua or ruach hakodesh?

Tags: nevua-prophecy, talmud-yerushalmi, masechet-sukkah, ruach-hakodesh

What is greater: nevua or ruach hakodesh?

Which one is a higher level, prophecy or holy spirit?

In *Yerushalmi Succa*  Perek  1 Halacha 5 we find Yona ben Amiti, a novi, went to simchas beis hashuava and had ruach hakodesh.

But if he was a novi, ruch hakodesh is not as great seemingly.

See Rambam. *Hilchos Yesode* *hatora Perek* 7 *Halacha* 1.

Comment: They are two different things, One is actually coming from the other. Nevua, or prophecy is coming from the Holy Spirit.

Comment: See Rambam in the Moreh Nevuchim  חלק שני פרק מ"ה - he ranks the levels of nevuah.

Comment: If _Y'sode Hatora_ 7:1 is important to your question, would you please include it in English instead of just including a citation? As a rule, the easier you make it for people to understand your question, the more likely it is that it'll be answered.

Answer (score 2):

it seems prophecy is a higher level than ruach hakodesh as Rabbi Chaim Vital brings in gate 4 of shaarei kedusha

"After a man has merited to the deveikut, he will merit to the secret of 'equality' (hishtavut), and if he merits the secret of 'equality', he will merit to the secret of 'meditation', and after he has merited to the secret of 'meditation', he will merit Ruach HaKodesh, and from this to prophecy", which means, he will prophecy and say over future events".